# How do you find the number of solutions to $|(2x-\pi)\csc2x|=2$?

Tags: trigonometry

What are the solutions for the equation $|(2x-\pi)\csc2x|=2$?

My approach was to draw the graph of $|(2x-\pi)\csc2x|$ but it seemed to be too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left| (2 x-\pi ) \csc 2x\right| =2$$
is verified when
$$(2 x-\pi ) \csc 2x=2\text{ or }(2 x-\pi ) \csc 2x=-2$$
This can be rewritten as
$$x-\frac{\pi}{2}=\sin 2x\text{ or }\frac{\pi}{2}-x=\sin 2x$$
The first equation has the solution $\frac{\pi}{2}$ discarded as $\csc 2x$ fail to exist at that value.

The second equation can be graphed as below and the equation has only two solutions $x_1\approx 0.623049, x_2\approx 2.51854$.

---

[image]

Comment: How can I show that with a pen and paper sir .I cannot bring graphing calculators to my exam .

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox I edited my answer. Should be easier now